# How to read and generate X.509 certificate stored on usb token in js

Tags: javascript, x509, pkcs#11

I am using Gemalto usb token for my Javascript application.
I am accessing token's functionality through PKCS11 Javascript library.

I've been able to: 
Generate public and private key, encrypt/decrypt, sign/verify.

But the main problem is: 
How can i read attributes of certificate stored inside the token using Javascript code?, so that I can move on to the next step, which will be the signature of the pdf document via this certificate (always using javascript).

I thoroughly looked through the PKCS#11 documentation, and over the Internet, but I couldn't find answer to my question.

I would appreciate any hints to solve this problem.
Thanks...

Comment: As far as I know there are exists PKCS#11 vendor extensions API and one of this function is called [pkcs7Sign](https://developer.aladdin-rd.ru/archive/pkcs11/2.1.0/api/nonstandard/pki.html#pkcs7sign) Sorry there are no English version, but parameter types and names are self-explaining.

Comment: You can also check this [repo](https://github.com/open-eid/digidoc4j/)

Comment: Hi @Alexander, Thank you for reply . But in my case i want to get the X.509 certificat from my token using only javascript, and even the signature of PDF file will be in javascript code.